# Yii: Catching all exceptions for a specific controller

Tags: yii

I am working on a project which includes a REST API component. I have a controller dedicated to handling all of the REST API calls.

Is there any way to catch all exceptions for that specific controller so that I can take a different action for those exceptions than the rest of the application's controllers?

IE: I'd like to respond with either an XML/JSON formatted API response that contains the exception message, rather than the default system view/stack trace (which isn't really useful in an API context). Would prefer not having to wrap every method call in the controller in its own try/catch.

Thanks for any advice in advance.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can completely bypass Yii's default error displaying mechanism by registering **onError** and **onException** event listeners.

Example:

```php
class ApiController extends CController
{
  public function init()
  {
    parent::init();

    Yii::app()->attachEventHandler('onError',array($this,'handleError'));
    Yii::app()->attachEventHandler('onException',array($this,'handleError'));
  }

  public function handleError(CEvent $event)
  {        
    if ($event instanceof CExceptionEvent)
    {
      // handle exception
      // ...
    }
    elseif($event instanceof CErrorEvent)
    {
      // handle error
      // ...
    }

    $event->handled = TRUE;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried all sort of things but your solution is by far the best way to override error/exception handler for things like API controller.

Comment: Careful if one has an `ErrorHandler` that may catch the exception before your controller has the chance. I got bitten by a few custom exception handlers in my code base that would take precedence. Look for occurences of `  addExceptionHandler` calls in your codebase.  I dropped this approach and attached a new errorh andler before the catch-all ones and I had to search for and building a handler implementing the `IExceptionHandler`. One may has to change the approach to throw more specific exceptions from the controller in question.

Answer (score 9):

I wasn't able to attach events in controller, and I did it by redefinition CWebApplication class:

```
class WebApplication extends CWebApplication
{
protected function init()
{
    parent::init();

    Yii::app()->attachEventHandler('onError',array($this, 'handleApiError'));
    Yii::app()->attachEventHandler('onException',array($this, 'handleApiError'));
}

/**
 * Error handler
 * @param CEvent $event
 */
public function handleApiError(CEvent $event)
{
    $statusCode = 500;

    if($event instanceof CExceptionEvent)
    {
        $statusCode = $event->exception->statusCode;
        $body = array(
            'code' => $event->exception->getCode(),
            'message' => $event->exception->getMessage(),
            'file' => YII_DEBUG ? $event->exception->getFile() : '*',
            'line' => YII_DEBUG ? $event->exception->getLine() : '*'
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $body = array(
            'code' => $event->code,
            'message' => $event->message,
            'file' => YII_DEBUG ? $event->file : '*',
            'line' => YII_DEBUG ? $event->line : '*'
        );
    }

    $event->handled = true;

    ApiHelper::instance()->sendResponse($statusCode, $body);
}
}
```

In index.php:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/protected/components/WebApplication.php');
Yii::createApplication('WebApplication', $config)->run();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own actionError() function per controller. There are several ways of doing that described [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/15484-custom-errorhandler-for-specific-controller/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following Base controller for an API, it's not stateless API, mind you, but it can serve just aswell.

class BaseJSONController extends CController{

```
        public $data = array();

        public $layout;

        public function filters()
        {
                return array('mainLoop');
        }

        /**
         * it all starts here
         * @param unknown_type $filterChain
         */
        public function filterMainLoop($filterChain){
                $this->data['Success'] = true;
                $this->data['ReturnMessage'] = "";
                $this->data['ReturnCode'] = 0;
                try{
                        $filterChain->run();

                }catch (Exception $e){
                        $this->data['Success'] = false;
                        $this->data['ReturnMessage'] = $e->getMessage();
                        $this->data['ReturnCode'] = $e->getCode(); 
                }

                echo json_encode($this->data);
        }
}
```

You could also catch dbException and email those, as they're somewhat critical and can show underlying problem in the code/db design.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your controller:

```
Yii::app()->setComponents(array(
    'errorHandler'=>array(
        'errorAction'=>'error/error'
    )
));
```